# Nested json from numpy arrays

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have created a ML Classifier that outputs probabilities of an item belonging to particular class. For example, for two items being predicted:

`array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2], [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2]])`

However, I have been asked to provide my results in predefined json structure which looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Scores": [
            {
                "class": "A",
                "probability": "0.1"
            },
            {
                "class": "B",
                "probability": "0.2"
            },
            {
                "class": "C",
                "probability": "0.5"
            },
            {
                "class": "D",
                "probability": "0.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Scores": [            
            {
                "class": "A",
                "probability": "0.2"
            },
            {
                "class": "B",
                "probability": "0.1"
            },
            {
                "class": "C",
                "probability": "0.5"
            },
            {
                "class": "D",
                "probability": "0.2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Which I am struggling with. How can I do this assuming that class order remains the same across all the predictions?

Comment: "Which I am struggling with." What happened when you tried to write the code? Do you know the rule that tells you how data in the input should correspond to the output structure? Do you know how to create lists and dicts, and to modify their contents? What happened when you tried taking out a pencil and paper and writing out, step by step (in plain English, possibly with flowchart symbols) a procedure to follow in order to create the needed data structure?

Comment: Not sure I get you. `Scores` is expected to be a list which maintains order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a nested list comprehension to achieve this.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> predictions = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2], [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2]])
>>> data = [{'ID':idx, 'Scores': [{'class': letter, 'probability': p} for letter, p in zip('ABCD', sub)]} for idx, sub in enumerate(predictions, 1)]
>>> data
[{'ID': 1, 'Scores': [{'class': 'A', 'probability': 0.1}, {'class': 'B', 'probability': 0.2}, {'class': 'C', 'probability': 0.5}, {'class': 'D', 'probability': 0.2}]}, {'ID': 2, 'Scores': [{'class': 'A', 'probability': 0.2}, {'class': 'B', 'probability': 0.1}, {'class': 'C', 'probability': 0.5}, {'class': 'D', 'probability': 0.2}]}]
```

Basically for each sub-array, you can `enumerate` to get the corresponding `'ID'`. Then for each probability you can `zip` against `'ABCD'` to get the corresponding `'class'`.